# operator like »keyof«, but for values

Tags: typescript

There is this code:

```
type LoadEvents = "load-start" | "load-end";
type BootEvents = "boot-start" | "boot-end";

interface EventObject {}
interface LoadEvent extends EventObject {}
interface BootEvent extends EventObject {}

type EventMap = { [key in LoadEvents]: LoadEvent } &
                { [key in BootEvents]: BootEvent }

type AllEventNames = keyof EventMap;
```

**Question:**

What can I do to get `AllEventTypes` which is essentially the same as `AllEventNames` but instead a list of all keys in `EventMap`, a list of all values in `EventMap`. So in this example that would be `LoadEvent | BootEvent`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, you just have to index the original type by `keyof KeyType` so something like

```
type AllEventNames = EventMap[keyof EventMap];
```

works here

Comment: That's it! `EventMap[AllEventNames]` does even shortcut that...